# How module checks if syntax is correct?

Tags: syntax, kernel

I would like to understand the following module subtlety.
Consider two seemingly equivalent instances

```
Module[{temp}, Sequence[x, x]]
```

(*Module::argrx: Module called with 3 arguments; 2 arguments are expected.*)

and

```
Module[{temp}, temp = Sequence[x, x]]
```

(*Sequence[x, x]*)

While the first complains about bad syntax (three arguments instead of expected two), the second performs as expected. Why the difference?

Comment: `Module[{temp}, Sequence[x, x]]` becomes `Module[{temp}, x, x]` hence the error. But  `Module[{temp}, temp = Sequence[x, x]]` remains as is. `Sequence[x, x]` should become `x,x` in function calls. I admit I do not know why it unwrapped in the first usage you had instead of remaining `Sequence[x, x]` but this is what Mathematica did.  You can see the automatic unwrapping if you type `foo[Sequence[x, x]]` then becomes `foo[x,x]`

Comment: @Nasser After reading your comment I started to think and now seems understand what is going here. Sequence starts to unwrap inside closest head. In the first case it is Module and this produces error. In the second case it tries to unwrap inside Set. However Set is very different form other command and it prevents unwrapping. Therefore the second case works as expected.

Comment: The difference here is from the fact that `Module` has attribute `HoldAll` but not `SequenceHold` whereas `Set` has attribute `SequenceHold`.